# Return just the rowKeys - no other qualifer/value

Tags: hbase, hbase-shell

```
scan 'TaxWashSales', {ROWPREFIXFILTER=>'999_524723_3_20230929_', FILTER=> "FirstKeyOnlyFilter() AND KeyOnlyFilter()"}
```

ROW                                                          COLUMN+CELL

944_524723_3_20230929_24934901_24995426_24740068            column=c:a, timestamp=2023-10-12T12:15:57.132, value=
944_524723_3_20230929_24934901_24995426_24740069            column=c:a, timestamp=2023-10-12T12:15:57.132, value=
944_524723_3_20230929_24934901_24995426_24740070            column=c:a, timestamp=2023-10-12T11:32:28.589, value=

3 row(s)
Took 0.0088 seconds

It would still return the first qualifier name (not its value). Well, I don't want the name of the first qualifier for my row; all I need is the RowKey.

How can I do it?

Comment: Any help is appreciated.